# Why semicolon (;) are added when use HTML2Text handle method

Tags: python-3.x

When i use html2text in python3 then i receive wrong string

```
import html2text

str = "f42aac23083&s=604A3965"

h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.ignore_emphasis = True
h.body_width = 0
html = h.handle(str)



print(str)  # f42aac23083&s=604A3965
print(html) #  f42aac23083&s;=604A3965\n\n
```